# How to load image under header tag in django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

all other images that are under "img" tag are loading successfully, but i have one image under "header" tag, like this:

```
<header class="pt100 pb100 parallax-window-2" data-parallax="scroll" data-speed="0.5" data-image-src="{% static 'assets/img/serv.jpg' %}" data-positionY="1000">
```

but this image is not loading, can anybody suggest, how to overcome this issue?

when i run the raw template in browser, the image loads without any issue, but unable to making it work with django!

Comment: Which error/status do you get requesting this image url? What do you mean by "when i run the **raw template** in browser"?

Comment: @IvanStarostin i didn't get any error but the image does not shows up. by raw template i mean basic primary templates, where no dajngo syntax are used and that is not being runs through django, normal html that can be opened in any browser & here the image shows up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed this issue by adding an **"style"** tag and remove the

> data-image-src="{% static 'assets/img/serv.jpg' %}"

as django was not able to load the image, when we use **data-image-src** like syntax, i still don't get it, why it was not working with django, if anybody knows the reason, please let me know.

```
<header class="pt100 pb100 parallax-window-2" data-parallax="scroll" data-speed="0.5" data-positionY="1000"  style="background-image: url({% static 'assets/img/serv.jpg' %}); background-position: center;">
```